# Entering an If statement with a hashmap conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap

```
for (int i = 0; i < pac.length; i++)
{
   for (int j=0;j<mem.length;j++)
   {
      String[] words = mem[j].split(" ");
      for (int k = 1; k < words.length; k++)
      {
        if (words[k].equals(pac[i])
        {                          //done system.out.println here and it's right
            if (!members.containsKey(pac[i]))          //won't enter this if correctly
            {
               members.put(pac[i], " " + words[0]);      
            }
            else
            {
               String old = members.get(pac[i]);
               members.put(pac[i], old + " " + words[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            members.put(pac[i], "");
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I need the code to take an array pac which contains a list of organizations and then a list of people's names with their organizations after. I have to put them into a hashmap of members. I cant seem to get it to enter the if statement correctly though. It reaches there correctly. I've used the printing to see what should go into it and that part is correct. Members is an empty hashmap yet all but only one iteration of the loops will go into the first if statement when most should go into it.

Comment: It seems that the outter if does not have a end bracket in your code.

Comment: It's a typo, it's fixed now.

Comment: "all but only one iteration of the loops will go into the first if statement when most should go into it." All but? Could you clarify how many times you expect `if (!members.containsKey(pac[i]))` to be true as long as `pac[i]` does not change? (If your answer is not "one", think again.)

Answer (score 0):

use label you can solve your problem. because any one iteration of 2nd loop can empty your member. try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < pac.length; i++) {
            action: 
            for (int j = 0; j < mem.length; j++) {
                String[] words = mem[j].split(" ");
                for (int k = 1; k < words.length; k++) {
                    //System.out.println(words[0] + "ttt");
                    if (words[k].equals(pac[i])) { 
                        System.out.println(words[k]);
                        if (!members.containsKey(pac[i]))  
                        {
                            members.put(pac[i], " " + words[0]);
                            break action;
                        } else {
                            String old = members.get(pac[i]);
                            members.put(pac[i], old + " " + words[0]);
                            break action;
                        }
                    } else {
                        members.put(pac[i], "");
                    }
                }
                }
}
```

and use persons as a key for members instead of organization. because a org have more number of persons.